# Geometric interpretation of Lagrange's mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

What could be the geometric interpretation of Lagrange’s mean value theorem for the function of two variables?
For one variable it is quite clear, but what about for function of two variables?
Is it possible, that we are suppose to construct some direction vectors and use cross product to generate a plane and via that plane explain it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: I don't think so. For function of several variables it gets much more hard to imagine, but for two it might be possible. Just my opinion.

Comment: A line segment in $n$-space is just a line segment.  Look at the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables